# How to update MongoDB @DbRef embedded collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

So, I am trying my hands-on MongoDB CRUD operations using spring-data-mongodb. Below are my model classes,

```
@Document(collection = "alumni_students")
public class AlumniStudent {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @DBRef
    private AlumniDepartment alumniDepartment;
    
    @DBRef
    private List<AlumniSubject> alumniSubjects;
    
    ... getters/setters


@Document(collection = "alumni_department")
public class AlumniDepartment {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String departmentName;

    private String location;

    ... getters/setters


@Document(collection = "alumni_subjects")
public class AlumniSubject {
    
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String subjectName;
    
    private int marks;

    ... getters/setters
```

I am using MongoRepository for individual collections for their operations like below,

```
@Repository
public interface AlumniStudentRepository extends MongoRepository<AlumniStudent, String> { }

@Repository
public interface AlumniDepartmentRepository extends MongoRepository<AlumniDepartment, String> {}

@Repository
public interface AlumniSubjectRepository extends MongoRepository<AlumniSubject, String> {}
```

I have so far done good while creation and getting the student details. The issue I am facing is while updating the student data. In that also specifically while updating the data, I am confused as hell.

Below is my update code from service layer,

> ```
> @Autowired    
> AlumniStudentRepository alumniStudentRepo;    
> @Autowired    
> AlumniDepartmentRepository alumniDeptRepo;    
> @Autowired    
> AlumniSubjectRepository alumniSubjRepo;
>
>  public AlumniStudent updateStudent(AlumniStudent student, String id) {
>       Optional<AlumniStudent> fetchedStudent = alumniStudentRepo.findById(id);
>       **// UPDATE STUDENT DATA, WORKS FINE**
>       if (fetchedStudent.isPresent()) {
>           AlumniStudent studentFromDB = fetchedStudent.get();
>           studentFromDB.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
>           studentFromDB.setLastName(student.getLastName());
>           studentFromDB.setEmail(student.getEmail());
>
>       **// UPDATE DEPARTMENT DATA, WORKS FINE**
>       if (student.getAlumniDepartment() != null) {
>           Optional<AlumniDepartment> deptData = alumniDeptRepo.findById(studentFromDB.getAlumniDepartment().getId());
>           if (deptData.isPresent()) {
>               AlumniDepartment alumniDepartment = deptData.get();
>               alumniDepartment.setDepartmentName(student.getAlumniDepartment().getDepartmentName());
>               alumniDepartment.setLocation(student.getAlumniDepartment().getLocation());
>               alumniDeptRepo.save(alumniDepartment);
>               studentFromDB.setAlumniDepartment(alumniDepartment);
>           }
>       }
>       
>       **// UPDATE SUBJECTS ARRAY DATA.... HOW TO DO THIS?**
>       if (student.getAlumniSubjects() != null && !student.getAlumniSubjects().isEmpty()) {
>           
>        // Problematic area. How to perform update of arraylist here?
>
>
>       }
>       return alumniStudentRepo.save(studentFromDB);
>       }
>   }
> ```

This is the URL to hit in postman :

> localhost:8080/alumnistudents/60aa384ffbf1851f56c71bef

And this is the request body:

```
{
   "firstName": "Babita",
   "lastName": "Raman",
   "email": "babita@gmail.com",
   "alumniDepartment": {
        "departmentName": "Android Developer",
        "location": "Dubai"
    },
   "alumniSubjects": [
        {
            "subjectName": "Java",
            "marks": 80
        },
        {
            "subjectName": "Unit testing",
            "marks": 60
        },
        {
            "subjectName": "Docker",
            "marks": 80
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried some random code but ended up with

> Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.

Can someone help here with how to update the arrays data which is referenced as @DbRef ?

Thanks in advance everyone.